# Add extra module to ansible

Tags: centos, yum, automation, ansible

I have installed ansible to make automation deploy my system and i need some extra module to work with it. I downloaded module yumrepo.py on ansible github and add it to my library directory. But when i run, it show error `ERROR: yumrepo is not a legal parameter of an Ansible Play`. Here is my configuration in file ansible.cfg.

```
inventory      = /etc/ansible/hosts
library        = /etc/ansible/module/
remote_tmp     = $HOME/.ansible/tmp
```

and my playbook

```
---
- name: Add multiple repositories into the same file (1/2)
  yumrepo:
    name: epel
    description: EPEL YUM repo
    file: external_repos
    baseurl: http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/$releasever/$basearch/
    gpgcheck: no
```

Hope anybody help me. Thank so much

Comment: Which version of ansible did you install?

Comment: Is that your entire playbook?  If so then it's not formed quite right.  You need to specify the hosts to run against at the very least.  Take a look at the sample playbooks [here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_intro.html) for the correct format & pay particular attention to 'hosts', and 'tasks'.

Answer (score 1):

Which repository did you download `yumrepo.py` from?

What you should probably be using instead is the `ansible-yumrepo` **role** : https://github.com/picotrading/ansible-yumrepo (See here for [more about roles](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_roles.html#roles))

You can install this in a `roles` directory which can be in the same directory as your playbook. I found I needed to rename the role from `ansible-yumrepo` to `yumrepo` locally when I cloned the repository from github.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/picotrading/ansible-yumrepo.git roles/yumrepo
```

Then the following playbook can be used as a *starting point* for what you want to do:

```
- hosts: all
  roles:
    - role: yumrepo
      yumrepo_repos:
        myrepo1:
          name: epel
          description: EPEL YUM repo
          file: external_repos
          baseurl: http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/$releasever/$basearch/
          gpgcheck: no
```

Answer (score 1):

yumrepo is provided by [ansible-extras](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-extras) The problem is most likely that a version of this module that contains yumrepo has not yet been released. If you check the extras directory in your ansible installation you can verify this. Mine is at:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/extras/packaging/os/
ls -ltr
```

You will see that there is no yumrepo.py file. One solution is therefore as someone has already suggested clone the yumrepo role into your roles directory instead of trying to use the module. If you're absolutely set on using this module you can copy this yumrepo.py module from the github repo into a directory say ~/unreleased-ansible-extras and add it to your ANSIBLE_LIBRARY environment variable as per http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/developing_modules.html

e.g.

```
export ANSIBLE_LIBRARY=$ANSIBLE_LIBRARY:~/unreleased-ansible-extras
```

but it's probably better you just use the role and wait for the next release for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

Place the module file in `playbooks/library`  it will automatically pick it up, do not change your default ANSIBLE_LIBRARY vars, just use what it install with yum/pip.  Also, don't put them in a subdirectory.

You'll have something like...

```
hosts/hostfile
hosts/group_vars/all/custom_vars.yml
playbooks/library/plugin.py
playbooks/library/plugin2.py
playbooks/roles
playbooks/my_playbook.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my extras packages in 

`/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/modules/extras/`

and I've installed Ansible via `pip`, but still `yumrepo` is not present.